# VS Code weird error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a hierarchy of packages like this:

```
dir/
    subdir1/
        __init__.py
        module3.py
        module4.py
    __init__.py
    module1.py
    module2.py
```

There is a `msg` variable in module2 and module4 respectively.

I import module2 in module1, and it works:

```
import module2
print(module2.msg)
```

But when I import module4 in module3, vscode gives me the error: `[pylint] E0401:Unable to import 'module4'`. However, when I run it by `python .\subdir1\module3.py`, python interpreter doesn't complain this and run smoothly:

```
import module4
print(module4.msg)
```

[image]

What's the problem?

EDIT: [image]

Comment: you should type `import subdir1.module4` , also i smell a duplicate of this somewhere.

Comment: @Abra001 I spent over 4 hours on how to import modules in python yesterday. But I still get stuck with it. As for this problem, vscode give error on that `import module4`, but actuallly there is no error when I run it. And when I change that line to `import subdir1.module4`, vscode doesn't complain error though, but when I run it, python give me error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subdir1'`. Please help me, is there something I messed up?

Comment: @Abra001 I added a screen shot.

Comment: the main code should be in the root dir, not in a subdir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're executing the module directly as a file path. Python doesn't know `module3` is in the `subdir1` package, so it can't resolve the import. If you did `python -m subdir1.module3` it will work.

Comment: Thanks very much @Brett. Could you tell me what's the problem with `import module4` in `module3.py`? Because VScode say there is an error with it(the first picture). But actually when I run it, there is no error.

Comment: @Bicheng It's because you are not doing a relative import. Do `from . import module4`.

Comment: So, although `import module4` can work, but I still SHOULD use `from . import module4`?

Comment: That will only work in Python 2 or if you are directly executing `module3` which as I said you shouldn't be doing.